# How to understand transposition in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to compute $(5 6)(3 5)$, and the result I get is $(1 2 6 4 3 5)$. My steps are as the following:

1. swap positions of $3$ and $5$:
   $$(3 5) = \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
       1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 6
     \end{pmatrix}$$
2. swap positions of $5$ and $6$
   $$(5 6)(3 5) = \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
       1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 6\\
       1 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 5
    \end{pmatrix}$$

But the result seems to be \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
    1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 3
  \end{pmatrix}

Can anyone explain to me where I did wrong?

Comment: Consult your notes, looks like a matter of the order of the composition (i.e. if $fg(x)=f(g(x))$ or $fg(x)=g(f(x))$. you've done the former, correctly, while the latter is rarer but sometimes shows up in some algebra texts, and usually in the form where function application is also reversed)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6
  \end{pmatrix} \overset{\begin{pmatrix}3 & 5\end{pmatrix}}{\rightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 6
  \end{pmatrix} \overset{\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}}{\rightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 3
  \end{pmatrix}$

rather than $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6
  \end{pmatrix} \overset{\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}}{\rightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 5
  \end{pmatrix} \overset{\begin{pmatrix}3 & 5\end{pmatrix}}{\rightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 5
  \end{pmatrix}$

So the difference is the order in which the operations are applied. Typically the notes will clarify which direction they're using but all the texts I own prefer evaluating from the right to the left as in the first case.

Comment: There's also the question of whether $(56)$ means swapping the actual numbers $5$ and $6$ (wherever they happen to be), or swapping whatever numbers are currently in column $5$ and column $6$.